# checkboxlist not rendering checkbox checked correctly

Tags: yii2

I have a two array that I'm going to include them into  a checkbox,

```
echo Html::checkboxList('item', $selectedItem, $dataItem, [
                'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
                       return "<label class='col-md-2'>
                            <input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='{$name}' value='{$value}'>
                                <span>{$label}</span>
                               </label>";
                        }
                    ]);
```

I see in code in browser like this :

```
<label class="col-md-2">
       <input 1="" name="item[]" value="1" disabled="" type="checkbox">
      <span>Login</span>
</label>
```

The checked render into `1=""` .

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

**$dataItem**

```
E:\wamp64\www\yii_tresnamuda\modules\it\views\request\preview.php:128:
   array (size=6)
    1 => string 'Login' (length=5)
    2 => string 'Printer' (length=7)
    3 => string 'Monitor' (length=7)
    4 => string 'Computer' (length=8)
    5 => string 'Network' (length=7)
    6 => string 'Lain Lain' (length=9)
```

**$selectedItem**

```
E:\wamp64\www\yii_tresnamuda\modules\it\views\request\preview.php:129:
  array (size=2)
    2 => int 2
    1 => int 1
```

Comment: Post `var_dump` of `$selectedItem` and `$dataItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `{$checked}` element of your `item` template. Try this:

```
echo Html::checkboxList('item', $selectedItem, $dataItem, [
  'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
    return "<label class='col-md-2'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='{$name}' value='{$value}' ".($checked ? 'checked' : '').">
        <span>{$label}</span>
     </label>";
    }
]);
```

Also, I think you have to change `$selectedItem` specification form `[2=>2, 1=>1]` to just `[2,1]`

Comment: Thanks, worked. First, I will analyzed your comment then I get why it worked. GBU